# Equality relationship between Total Variation and KL divergence

Tags: probability-theory, total-variation, information-geometry

I noticed that according to Pinsker's inequality, the following relationship can be got.

$D_{TV}(p||q) \le \sqrt{{1\above{1pt}2}D_{KL}(p||q)} $.

I'm curious whether, under some condition, the equality relationship between them can be got

$D_{TV}(p||q) = \sqrt{{1\above{1pt}2}D_{KL}(p||q)} $

Comment: They are equal when $p = q$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Of course, this is for sure. But if $p≠q$, this equality relationship could be satisfied ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $ p ≠ q $ it is not generally possible. The reason is that these two distances measure different aspects of the dissimilarity between the distributions. In some specific cases, the equality might be achieved, but these cases are not general and would depend on particular properties of the probability distributions $p$ and $q$. In general, Pinsker's inequality only provides an upper bound on the total variation distance using the Kullback-Leibler divergence, and the relationship between the two is not generally an equality.

Comment: What are these special cases? Could the Gaussian distribution meets ? would you please tell me some details ?

Comment: Let p and q be two discrete probability distributions over a two-element set {0, 1} with the following probabilities:  
$p(0) = 1, p(1) = 0$  
$q(0) = 1 - ε, q(1) = ε$  
where $ε$ is a small positive number $(0 < ε << 1)$.  
$D_TV(p, q) = 1/2 * (|p(0) - q(0)| + |p(1) - q(1)|) = 1/2 * (|1 - (1 - ε)| + |0 - ε|) = ε/2$  
$D_KL(p || q) = p(0) * log(p(0) / q(0)) + p(1) * log(p(1) / q(1))$ ($p(1) = 0$)  
$D_KL(p || q) = p(0) * log(p(0) / q(0)) = 1 * log(1 / (1 - ε)) ≈ ε$.
So we have $(ε/2)^2 ≈ 1/2 * ε$. Note that this is a very simple example, and the equality is only approximately true

Comment: For Gaussian it's also not true in general. Calculating the total variation distance $D_{TV}(p, q)$ for Gaussian distributions does not have a closed-form expression. Directly comparing $D_{TV}(p, q)$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}D_{KL}(p || q)}$ is not straightforward.

Comment: As I said before special cases would depend on particular properties of the probability distributions p and q.

Comment: Is there a good way for me to compute the $D_{TV}(p||q)$ about two Gaussian distribution ? @rumathe

Comment: You can use numerical integration methods, such as the trapezoidal rule, Simpson's rule, or Gauss quadrature, to approximate $D_{TV}(p, q) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |p(x) - q(x)| dx$.

Comment: But the $D_{TV}$ I want to calculate is based on a high-dimensional space, not from $-∞$ to $∞$, thus I'm afraid of the numerical integration can be invalid.

Comment: In such cases, you can consider using alternative methods like Monte Carlo integration, which can handle high-dimensional spaces more effectively. However, even with Monte Carlo integration, the accuracy of the approximation may vary depending on the specific distributions and the number of samples used.